# Error recovery in an LALR(1) grammar

Tags: grammar, yacc, lex, lalr

I'm using some parser and lexer generating tools (similar to Lex and Bison, but for C#) to generate programs that parse strings into abstract syntax trees that can later be evaluated.

I wanted to do error recovery (i.e. report in the produced abstract sentence tree that there are missing tokens and such).  I had two approaches in mind to structuring the generated grammars, and I was wondering **which approach was better/more flexible/wouldn't have conflicts** (the .y and .lex files are generated based on a description of the calculator).

The calculator description allows the user to specify terminals/regex's and their placement for operators and the associativity.  So something like:

```
grammar.AddTerminal("Plus", "\\+").
    AddNonTerminal(new NonTerminal("Add", Associativity.LeftToRight).
        AddTerminal("Expression").
        AddTerminal("Plus").
        AddTerminal("Expression"));
```

(Precedence is specified via the order that the `Terminal`'s and `NonTerminal`'s are added. `"Add"` is the name of a method that is discovered via Reflection.  Basically it tells the NonTerminal what to call the operator in the abstract syntax tree.)

---

**Approach 1**: (allow the empty rule for any expression)

```
S -> E
E -> E + T
E -> T
T -> T * P
T -> P
P -> (E)
P -> (E [error]
P -> a
P -> @ [error]
```

---

`a` is a terminal.
`@` is empty.

---

**Approach 2**: (only allow the empty rule for the start rule)

```
S -> E
S -> @ [error]
E -> + [error]
E -> T + [error]
E -> + T [error]
E -> E + T
E -> T
T -> * [error]
T -> * P [error]
T -> P * [error]
T -> T * P
T -> P
P -> (E)
P -> (E [error]
P -> a
```

Here's an example to show a left-most derivation for a bad-input using each approach.

---

**Input:** `(a +`

---

**Approach 1**:

```
S
E
T
P
(E
(E + T
(T + T
(P + T
(a + T
(a + P
(a +
```

---

**Approach 2**:

```
S
E
T
P
(E
(T +
(P +
(a +
```

---

Approach 2 is much harder to code for (consider subtraction/unary negative operator.  You can't just look at subtract `A -> A - B`, take out that first `A` and report an error on `A -> - B` because that's valid for the unary operator.)  I coded for approach 2 this morning only to find out that I think it has grammar issues and that an empty rule as in **Approach 1 makes things much simpler, code-wise, but my main concern is which approach would produce the least amount of grammar issues** as programmers create calculator descriptions as described above.

Comment: What does this have to with yacc?  yacc has a very specific error recovery scheme based on throwing away tokens to create something parseable.  It does not have an easy way of dealing with missing tokens.

Comment: Well the parsing tool I'm using is MPPG, which is a Microsoft branding of GPPG, which is a spin-off of Yacc.  Since the syntax is very similar for the .y files, I tagged it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been around for a while and covers a topic that is is often visited by beginners in the subject. One often find that those who have done a compilers course in their undergraduate degree know that this is one of those questions that has no easy or single answer. You might have noticed that you have [two questions on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940733/add-error-checking-via-production-rules-to-lalr1-grammar-to-handle-all-inputs), neither of which has been answered. [Another question someone else posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806955/can-parser-error-recovery-be-guided-automatically-by-the-grammar) was answered with pointers to the literature that explains why this is hard.

It is a question that has remained extant for over 50 years. If one examines the literature over time, from early conference papers, course textbooks, doctoral thesis and (today) `SO`, we can see regular references to the fact that this is *the wrong question*! (Or rather the wrong approach to the problem).

Just taking a sample from course texts over the years (random selections from my bookshelf):

Gries, D. (1970) Error Recovery and Correction - An introduction to the Literature, In *Compiler Construction, An advanced Course* edited by Bauer, F.L. & Eickel, J., Springer Verlag, pp.627-638.
Gries, D. (1971) *Compiler Construction for Digital Computers*, Wiley, pp.320-326.
Aho, A.V., Ullman, J.D. (1977) *Principles of Compiler Design*, Addison Wesley, pp.397-405.
Bornat, R. (1979) *Understanding and Writing Compilers*, Macmillan, pp.251-252.
Hanson, D. (1995) *A retargetable **C** compiler: Design and Implementation*,Addison-Wesley, pp.140-146.
Grune, D., Bal, H.E., Jacobs, C.J.H. & Langendoen, K.G. (2000) *Modern Compiler Design*, Wiley, pp.175-184.
Aho, A.V., Lam, M.S., Sethi, R., Ullman, J.D. (2007) *Compilers: Principles, Techniques, & Tools*, Pearson, Addison-Wesley, pp.283-296.

All of these concur (over a 40 year span) that your question is about using the wrong tools wrongly or going in the wrong direction. I think I'm trying to say "You can't there from here". You should start from somewhere else.

If you want something deeper, there is a whole Phd thesis:

[Charles, P. (1991) *A Practical method for Constructing Efficient LALR(k) Parsers with Automatic Error Recovery*, New York University](http://jikes.sourceforge.net/documents/thesis.pdf)

Hopefully, for those who visit this question again in the future, there is a placeholder for the answers.

---

I note from comments that you are using MPPG, derived from CPPG. Not everyone will have used these, so I'm including a couple of links to these tools:

[Managed Babel Systems Essentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165963%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[Garden Points Parser Generator](https://gppg.codeplex.com/)
[Irony .NET compiler Construction Kit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22650/Irony-NET-Compiler-Construction-Kit)
[Writing your first Visual Studio Language Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33250/Writing-Your-First-Visual-Studio-Language-Service)

Comment: I had thought this question should be flagged as "Too Broad", [but the flags eventually aged away](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away). The only other actions would be down vote or answer. I've now done all three.